# instantiate object (codecademy)

Tags: python

I typed the following code, printed the answers I was supposed to get (3 and True), but it keeps giving me an error, asking me if I "Created an instance in class Triangle called my_triangle". How can this be, if I in fact did intantiate my_triangle and even got the correct results with it?

```
class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
    number_of_sides = 3
    def check_angles(self):
        if self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180:
            return True
        else:
            return False
 my_triangle = Triangle(90, 30, 60)
 print my_triangle.number_of_sides
 print my_triangle.check_angles()
```

Comment: When you say "it keeps giving me an error", what do you mean? Are you getting an exception when you run the code? If so, please give the full traceback. If you're doing something else with the code (like submitting it somewhere for grading), we may not be able to help you much, since we won't know how the grading is done any better than you do.

Comment: the problem was indeed indentation...

Comment: If the answer below helped, you should "accept" it by clicking the check mark next to it on the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong. The last three lines need to be aligned all the way to the left.